# Counting row permutations that result in nonzero diagonals

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, permutations, directed-graphs, permutation-matrices

Let $A$ be a binary square matrix in {$0,1$}$^{n\times n}$. What is the number of row permutations that will result in nonzero diagonals? I.e., the number of permutation matrices $P$ s.t. the diagonal of $PA$ has no zero?

I have some intuition to relate it to n-rooks problem, or directed graphs (maybe with cycles). But I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Are there any constraints on $A$?  For example, the answer is obvious if every entry of $A$ is $1$.

Comment: @RobertShore no there's no constraints. I was thinking about a general characterization on such number. Of course one may start by assuming $A$ is invertible so at least such permutation exists.

Comment: @RobertShore Yes a full-one $A$ can be viewed as one extreme case. Another end of the extreme case is a unit lower/upper triangular $A$ where such row permutation is unique (can be seen from trace).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that we take the matrix $A$ to represent a balanced bipartite graph: one with vertices $v_1, v_2, \dots, v_n$ and $w_1, w_2, \dots, w_n$, and an edge $v_i w_j$ whenever $A_{ij}=1$.

Then a permutation matrix $P$ such that the main diagonal $PA$ consists of ones corresponds to a [perfect matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_matching): more precisely, if we permute the rows by permutation $\sigma$, then the edges $$v_1 w_{\sigma(1)}, v_2 w_{\sigma(2)}, \dots, v_n w_{\sigma(n)}$$ are the edges of a perfect matching in the graph.

[Hall's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall%27s_marriage_theorem) gives a condition for such a permutation to exist. (It is sufficient, but not necessary, for $A$ to be invertible; Hall's condition is both necessary and sufficient.) However, it is computationally difficult to compute the *number* of perfect matchings: the problem is ♯P-complete, which is an analog of NP-completeness for problems with numerical answers.

In particular, from the point of view of the matrix $A$, what we want to compute is the [permanent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permanent_(mathematics)) of $A$: a quantity defined similarly to the determinant, but as an *unsigned* sum of products. Wikipedia has [some more details](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computing_the_permanent) on how to compute this faster than brute force, though the result is still not going to be *efficient*.